# How to wrap columns two and two inside of a loop?

Tags: php, loops

I'm trying to wrap two columns inside of a row div from inside a php loop.

I came up with this test but it fails no matter what I do.. This is the closest I can come, I can't see where this logic fails.

Take a look:

```
<?php $i = 0; ?>
<?php while($i < 11) : ?>

  <?php if ($i % 2 === 0) : ?>

    <div class="row">row

  <?php endif; ?>

  <span><?php echo "[" . $i . "]"; ?></span>

  <?php if (!$i % 2 === 0) : ?>

     /row
    </div>

  <?php endif; ?>

  <?php $i++; ?>
<?php endwhile; ?>
```

The produced result:

```
row [0] [1] /row
row [2] /row
[3] /row
row [4] /row
[5] /row
row [6] /row
[7] /row
row [8] /row
[9] /row
row [10] /row
```

Here we can see that the first row is working great but then it becomes flawed somewhere in the logic, question is where?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Made a little changes to your code.

```
  <?php $i = 0; 
       while($i <= 11) :  
       if($i%2==0){
        echo '<div class="row"> Row';
       } 
         echo "[" . $i . "]"; 

       if($i%2!=0){
        echo " row </div>";
       }
       $i++; 
     endwhile; ?>
```

It will output

```
 Row[0][1] row
 Row[2][3] row
 Row[4][5] row
 Row[6][7] row
 Row[8][9] row
 Row[10][11] row
```

Comment: Works :) Why isn't (!$i % 2 === 0) and ($i % 2 !== 0) the same though? both returns false no?

Comment: no both are different things first will return false where as second will return true.. try it you will find it out

Comment: Ye just realised. Thanks for the help :)

Comment: This will not work when $i is 12 or any other even number.

Comment: you will need to keep it for all odd no's because your calculation wants two and 1 thats a odd no. if you do it for 12 or 10 the last row will be left unclosed. do one thing take your no in variable if its even no. then match the i value to its last value and if matched close the row

Answer (score 0):

Used another counter for columns.
Tested and seems to work: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/7374de00caef8a3f6b89a6196093326e8133c021

```
$col = 0;
for($i = 0; $i < 11; $i++){
  if($i % 2 == 0){
    echo '<div>';
  }

  echo "<span>[".$i."]</span>";
  $col++;

  if($col == 2){
    echo "</div>";
    $opened = false;
    $col = 0;
  }


}
```

Comment: This doesn't work. You only get 1 columns per row, and the second column gets put outside of a row div. Also you perform $i++ twice.

Comment: My bad, removed the $i++. While I didn't checked it - I believe it should output 2 cols per row (after removing the $i++ at least). Will check it again.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
<?php
  $count = 14;
  for($i = 0; $i <= $count; $i += 2) {
    if ($i % 2 == 0) {
       echo('row ');
    }

    echo('['.$i.']');
    if ($i < $count) {
      echo('['.($i+1).']');
    }

    if ($i % 2 == 0) {
       echo(' /row ');
    }
  }
?>
```

Result:

```
row [0][1] /row 
row [2][3] /row 
row [4][5] /row 
row [6][7] /row 
row [8][9] /row 
row [10][11] /row 
row [12][13] /row 
row [14] /row
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<style>
div {
    border: 1px red solid;
    width: 100px;
    padding: 3px;
    margin: 3px;
    text-align: center;
}
</style>
<?php

$i = 0;
while ($i < 11) :
$row = $i % 2 === 0;
?>

    <?php if ($row): ?><div><?php endif;?>
    <span><?php echo '[' . $i . ']'; ?></span>
    <?php if (!$row): ?></div><?php endif;?>

<?php
    $i++;
endwhile; ?>
```

output:

[image]